# Problemas com formatação miniatura de links

Tags: html

Bom, fiz um tópico mais cedo sobre o mesmo assunto, o conteúdo apareceu mas a imagem não aparece.

Segue o código:

```
<!--PARA ACEITAR ACENTOS-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!--CONTEÚDO EM PORTUGUÊS-->
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">

<!--URL DO SITE-->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.meudomínio.com/index.php">

<!--TÍTULO E NOME DO SITE-->
<meta property="og:title" content="TítuloSite">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome do site">

<!-- DESCRIÇÃO DO SITE-->
<meta property="og:description" content="descrição site.">  

<!-- IMAGEM DO SITE -->
<meta property="og:image" content="images/intro.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600">
```

Obs: eu verifiquei a extensão, eu tenho dúvida de um detalhe. A imagem é bem grande... e também está tudo no head.

Comment: Usa isso na partilha do facebook?

Comment: Usei o depurador do facebook e deu a seguinte mensagem:       A propriedade "og:image" deve ser fornecida explicitamente, mesmo que um valor possa ser deduzido a partir de outras tags.                                   As duas propriedades obrigatórias a seguir estão ausentes: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente vc está tendo problema com as tags que o Depurador acusou:

**og:url**

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.meusite.com.br/ola-mundo">
```

**og:title**

`<property="og:title">` Específica o título da página, assim como essa: "Esse é o nome da Minha página".

`<property="og:site_name">` Especifica o nome do site: StackOverflow.

**og:description**

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição da sua página">
```

Na sua tag **og:image:type** tente trocar o type para `content="image/jpg"` e não `.jpeg`

Vc pode ler mais sobre as `og:tags` aqui: https://tableless.com.br/utilizando-meta-tags-facebook/

Sobre a **`<meta property="fb:app_id">`** Ela é um "código de identificação" tipo `content="1234567890"` que vc tem que solicitar ao FaceBook. O assunto é mais denso, e vc tem que avaliar se vale a pena. Aqui tem a documenta~]ao oficial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects?locale=pt_BR

---

Agora sobre o tamanho da imagem. Nesse link tem as definições de boas práticas do FaceBook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Tamanhos de imagem: **(Para usar como o "avatar" eu recomendaria usar 200x200)**

> O tamanho mínimo de imagem é de 200 x 200 pixels. Se você tentar usar
>   uma imagem menor do que isso, você verá um erro no
>
> Tamanhos das imagens Use imagens com pelo menos 1200 x 630 pixels para
>   a melhor exibição em dispositivos de alta resolução. No mínimo, você
>   deve usar imagens que tenham 600 x 315 pixels para exibir publicações
>   na página com link com imagens maiores. O tamanho máximo das imagens é
>   de 8 MB.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro artigo interessante em inglês: https://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/how-to-use-og-image-meta-tag-facebook-reddit

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar o conteúdo. Vou dar uma lida em todos e insistir.