# A metatag og:image de OpenGraph não pega a imagem específica do link

Tags: html5, facebook

Estou com o seguinte trecho de código, porém o facebook está pegando aleatoriamente outra imagem que não faz parte do link específico para isso, o `og:image` conforme abaixo.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Acabamentos e Revestimentos">
<meta property="og:description" content="Acabamentos e Revestimentos Guarapari é o Guia Comercial de Guarapari com as melhores opções de Acabamentos e Revestimentos do mercado local.">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/acabamento-e-revestimento-guarapari">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/imagens/guia-comercial-rede-social.jpg">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117">
```

Todas as outras informações aparecem perfeitamente, apenas não pega a imagem especificada no link `og:image`.

Comment: Qual eh a dimensão da imagem em px? Já tentou não usar o http com vc fez e colocar o caminho da imagem direto na pasta?

Comment: Talvez seja cache, coloca o endereço do seu site na ferramenta [Debug do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), ela atualiza o cache da imagem.

Comment: @hugocsl Coloquei o caminho direto da imagem e nada.

Comment: @LucasGuima Utilizei a ferramenta Debug, mas não resolveu.

Comment: Cara da uma olhada nessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292925/problemas-com-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-miniatura-de-links/292949#292949

Comment: @hugocsl Quando vou no Debug do Facebook a meta tag aparece com uma url totalmente diferente da que coloquei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na declaração do `!DOCTYPE` das páginas do site:

```
           inválido
              ↓
<!DOCTYPE html!>
```

A exclamação `!` após o `html` é inválida, e com isso a API do Facebook não está validando o HTML da página, considerando que as *meta tags* não estão no `<head>`, conforme mostra o [Depurador de objetos do Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, a ferramenta escolhe aleatoriamente uma imagem da página.

Veja também o erro apontado no [validador de HTML do W3C](https://validator.w3.org/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Solução:** retirar a `!` e deixar apenas `<!DOCTYPE html>`, que é a declaração correta para o padrão HTML5.

Para testar, abra este link do depurador e verá a imagem correta:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws%2Fstack%2Ft6.php

O link acima do depurador aponta para **[esta página de teste](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t6.php)** que criei copiando o código-fonte do seu site e corrigindo o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo, tudo funcionando agora perfeitamente.